# Connect SharePoint and Microsoft Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm a newbie to Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010. Can you please help me with this assignment:

> Users wish to enter through the Microsoft Outlook planned absence so
>   that they will enter them in the calendar, which they will access
>   directly from Outlook. After entering the predicted absence of the
>   absence of such a view is their superior, who must approve or reject
>   the absence. Different employees have different superiors, so pairs
>   should be "employees" -> "superior" entered into a separate table in
>   SharePoint, which can be edited by the administrator, workflow validation must
>   find the appropriate supervisor for confirmation/certification in this table. The
>   result (absence of confirmed / denied) must be sended an email to the employee,
>   while the superior must get get e-mail in CC.

Comment: Try posting your question on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a calendar which is connected to outlook. When user adds new entry in outlook, that entry is added to the SharePoint calendar. In SharePoint you can start a workflow on Item Added on a calendar list. This workflow will do logic to kick of emails , approve/reject.

Comment: Ok, but I have no idea how to do that ... I have now list of contacts.